# Are questions about CPAN ok?

Tags: discussion, scope

I mean like if I wanted to ask 'how do I install a module with cpanp' would that be ok? obviously questions about how do I write a cpan module are offtopic and better relegated to SO.

Comment: It seems like we've done something wrong if two of the first three meta questions are on clarifying what's on-topic here; in theory we should've figured that out during [definition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3924?phase=definition)

Comment: @Michael:  It would be nice.  However, the discussion features aren't all that good, and the primary focus is on getting twenty people to agree that five questions are on-topic and five are off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is bound to be overlap here, but the implications of using CPAN on your nix system seem like something worth discussing here.

Comment: Presumably, if the user is on a Windows system and has a CPAN problem, he wouldn't think to _ask_ it on a "Unix & Linux" site. He might, however, find the answer he needs here via Google, which does fit into the idea of being a quality Q&A site. If the user says they're on Windows, then cote to close, otherwise CPAN questions seem like a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be something for (say) stackoverflow. CPAN and Perl are not *nix specific.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant to SO as it's not a programming question... it's closer to system administration because it's package management.

Comment: Also in a pre strawberry perl world, your standard cpan clients didn't work on windows perls. Active perl uses it's own thing. Making questions about the cpan client fairly *nix specific

Comment: I don't know why you don't think it's not a programming question. Perl is a programming language, installing packages to use in a language is a programming problem, and programming languages and their packages/libraries are tools used by programmers. That fits 3 of the 4 things that Stack Overflow covers.

Comment: @Thomas "installing packages to use in a language is a programming problem" -- no, it's not. There's no programming involved, and installing stuff doesn't mean you're a programmer. Entire applications are distributed via CPAN.

Answer (score 2):

If you're installing onto a Unix system I think it's on topic just like a question about "ls" is on topic.